# Wpf objectdataprovider composition

Tags: wpf, binding, properties, composition, objectdataprovider

suppose i have this class:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Bar aBar {get; private set;}

   public Foo(String name)
   {
      aBar = new Bar()
      {
         Name = name
      }
   }
}


public class Bar
{
       public String Name {get; private set;}
}
```

How can i access the property Name from class Foo?
this is what i have i XAML so far:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myFoo" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Foo}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                <system:String>HelloWorld</system:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

do i have to write a method, calling with Foo.aBar.Name, .. ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StaticResource` to access the `myFoo` object you've created in your window resources, then it's just a case of specifying the binding path as normal:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myFoo}, Path=aBar.Name }" />
```